# Disallowing Custom Attributes Together

Tags: .net, custom-attributes

Is there a design-time mechanism to check if two attributes are being applied to the same object?

I have created two attributes, [MyXAttribute] and [MyYAttribute], say, but I would like a design-time check to make sure only one is used on a field.

This is similar to using the AllowMultiple=false, except that applies to using two instances of the same attribute.

I tried inheriting from the same base Attribute, [MyAttribute], with AllowMultiple=false on that base, but there is no check.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the two attributes are mutually exclusive, then you might consider merging them, and then differentiating their usage with an enum or bool parameter. That way AllowMultiple=false will do the job for you.

Something like:

```
[MyAttributeXorY(MyAttributeEnum.X)]
```

Comment: I considered that and will do it if I can't find a more elegant way. Thanks for the idea.